# Process executing (exec) program

Tags: php

My program should read a user id and password. How to make it work through processes.

Answer (score 2):

1) Read up on the execl() function.  This function does not return.  When the validate program ends the child will exit.  Hence your write() calls never happen.

2) You appear to be calling execl() on the source code.  You would need to compile the source code into an executable program in order to run it this way.  Check if execl() is failing like this:

```
execl("/bin/bash", "bash", "-c", "echo hello", NULL); // Only returns if execl fails
perror("execl failed");
exit(1); // Make sure child exits if execl fails
```

3) After calling fork you should check for (pid==0) for the child.  You are incorrectly testing for (pid), which will be true for the parent not for the child.

4) The write() calls should be made by the parent, not by the child. After the child exec's it will become the validate program and will never return to your code.

That's a start.  Good luck!

Comment: added checking for execl failure to answer.

Comment: I think you just want to call your password checking function from the child; I don't think you really want to exec() in the child, but your original post didn't give enough detail as to what you're actually trying to do.